# Why does Solve give a wrong solution to an equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have got a following equation:

```
-(c - x)/Sqrt[b^2 + (c - x)^2] + x/Sqrt[a^2 + x^2] == 0.
```

Trying to solve it for x, so I evaluate

```
Solve[-(c-x)/Sqrt[b^2+(c-x)^2]+x/Sqrt[a^2+x^2] == 0,x].
```

This produces

> ```
> {{x -> (a*c)/(a - b)}, {x -> (a*c)/a + b)}}
> ```

It is obviously wrong. Well, the second solution `a c/(a + b)` is **indeed** the right one, but the first `a c/(a - b)` is obviously wrong. You can check it yourself with direct substitution (lets take `a = 2`, `b = 3`, `c = 4`):

```
(-(c - x)/Sqrt[b^2 + (c - x)^2] + x/Sqrt[a^2 + x^2])/. x -> a*c/(a - b) /.
   a ->  2 /. b -> 3 /.c -> 4
```

It produces `-(8/Sqrt[17])`. Not zero. So wrong.

Now lets try the same but with a c/(a + b):

```
(-(c - x)/Sqrt[b^2 + (c - x)^2] + x/Sqrt[a^2 + x^2])/. x -> a*c/(a + b) /.
   a ->  2 /. b -> 3 /.c -> 4
```

Produces zero. So what's wrong with `Solve`?

I'm using *Mathematica* 9.

Comment: The first can be correct and the second incorrect.  Try `{a -> 2, b -> -3, c -> 4}`.  `Solve` generally returns solutions that are valid over a generic component.  You might try `Solve[..., Reals]` if you're interested only in real solutions.  Or use `Reduce`, which warns you that the solution set might depend on branch cuts.

Comment: You can also try the option `MaxExtraConditions -> 1`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP argument that _Mathematica_ has found an invalid root is spurious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the option [`MaxExtraConditions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html)

> Solve gives generic solutions only. Solutions that are valid only when
>   continuous parameters satisfy equations are removed. Additional
>   solutions can be obtained by using nondefault settings for
>   MaxExtraConditions.

```
Solve[-(c - x)/Sqrt[b^2 + (c - x)^2] + x/Sqrt[a^2 + x^2] == 0, x, 
  MaxExtraConditions -> 1]

During evaluation of Solve::useq: The answer found by Solve contains equational condition(s) {0==-b-Sqrt[b^2],0==-a-Sqrt[a^2],0==-b-Sqrt[b^2],0==a-Sqrt[a^2],0==b-Sqrt[b^2],0==-a-Sqrt[a^2],0==b-Sqrt[b^2],0==a-Sqrt[a^2],0==(-a Sqrt[Power[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<4>>]]-b Sqrt[Power[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]])/b,<<11>>,0==b-Sqrt[b^2],0==-b-Sqrt[b^2],0==b-Sqrt[b^2],0==-b-Sqrt[b^2],0==b-Sqrt[b^2],0==b-Sqrt[b^2],0==b-Sqrt[b^2],0==b-Sqrt[b^2],0==(Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]^2] x-c Sqrt[x^2]+x Sqrt[x^2])/(c-x)}. A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions. >>
(* {{x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    0, (a + Sqrt[a^2] == 0 && b + Sqrt[b^2] == 0 && 
       c == 0) || (a + Sqrt[a^2] == 0 && 
       c == 0 && -b + Sqrt[b^2] == 0) || (b + Sqrt[b^2] == 0 && 
       c == 0 && -a + Sqrt[a^2] == 0) || (c == 0 && -b + Sqrt[b^2] == 
        0 && -a + Sqrt[a^2] == 0)]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[c/2, a == -b || a == b]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(a c)/(
    a - b), (a Sqrt[(b^2 (a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 + c^2))/(a - b)^2])/b + 
      Sqrt[a^2 + (a^2 c^2)/(a - b)^2] == 0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(a c)/(
    a + b), (a Sqrt[(b^2 (a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 + c^2))/(a + b)^2])/b - 
      Sqrt[a^2 + (a^2 c^2)/(a + b)^2] == 0]}} *)
```

A simpler example:

```
Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]
(* {{x -> (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}, 
    {x -> (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}} *)
```

The above solutions are only true if `a!=0`

```
Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x, MaxExtraConditions -> 1]
(* {{x -> (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}, 
    {x -> (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}, 
    {x -> ConditionalExpression[-(c/b), a == 0]}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your argument concluding that `(a c)/(a + b)` is a root but `(a c)/(a - b)` is not a root is not sound.

You accept that `(a c)/(a + b)` is a root because your equation is satisfied by the triple `{a, b, c} = {2, 3, 4}`. However, it immediately follows that `(a c)/(a - b)` has the same value when `{a, b, c} = {2, -3, 4}`. So by your own reasoning you should accept `(a c)/(a - b)` as a solution as well.